# Adding two big integers represented as strings

Tags: java, integer

```
class MyClass{
    static Integer carry = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1 = "7654729850328997631007285998163550104";
        String s2 = "5980139243970186632651869926335829102";
        add(s1, s2);
    }

    public static void add(String a, String b){
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder myString = null;
        int i = a.length() - 1;
        int j = b.length() - 1;
        while(true){
            int i1 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(a.charAt(i)));
            int i2 = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(b.charAt(j)));
            Integer i3  = i1 + i2 + carry;
            if(i3 > 9){
                carry = 1;
                i3 = i3 - 10;
            }else carry = 0;
            res.add(i3.toString());
            i--;j--;
            if(i < 0){
                res.add(carry.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
        Collections.reverse(res);
        for(String r : res){
            System.out.print(r);
        }
    }
}
```

This program adds 2 numbers whose length is greater than limit of Long. I think my logic is kind of bulky.  Can something be done to improve this?

Comment: Use `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: i forgot to remove 'myString' variable since i'm not using it

Comment: ok thanks for the link, i'll post this code there

Comment: Just use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). :)

Answer (score 7):

Loop structure's OK, logic's reasonably good. There is obviously a Java library alternative of `BigInteger`, but I assume you knew that. Some efficiency issues with excessive toString() and string-ification of what could be character operations.

Here are some tips:

1. Use `int` where nulls are not possible, not `Integer`.
2. `carry` is only used locally -- keep it local. Referencing it outside the method can only be erroneous, so it shouldn't be visibly exposed to make that possible..
3. Carry calculation from `i3` is OK here, but could in related algorithms be brittle -- it can't handle a digit-sum > 19 as the maximum carry it can produce is 1.
4. If addition completes with a carry of 0, it will output an unnecessary 0 digit.
5. If Strings are your inputs, you should probably build a String as the result via a StringBuilder -- not an ArrayList.
6. `myString` should be called `result` or `sb`, if you're building the result in it.
7. Build using StringBuilder in reverse order, and do it by character calculation `(char) (i3 + '0')` rather than toString() if you want to maximize efficiency.
8. Return the result from your function, and do the printing in main() instead. there. That way you have a general-purpose `add()` function and a fixed-purpose main() method for testing.

Is that complete enough?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i got some important pointers :)

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial refactoring, I have extracted some methods and fixed some problems. For example: if the two numbers have different lenghts, your program throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at it.test.refactor.MyClass.add(MyClass.java:21)
at it.test.refactor.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:11)
```

I'll do some more refactoring later :)

```
package it.test.refactor;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    private static final String DEFAULT1 = "00033000010";
    private static final String DEFAULT2 = "1";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 1 || args.length > 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MyClass integer1 integer2\n \n exemple: MyClass 123432 4321234");
            return;
        }
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Warning: using default parameters: " + DEFAULT1 + " + " + DEFAULT2);
            System.out.println(new TextualNumbers().add(DEFAULT1, DEFAULT2));
        } else {
            System.out.println(new TextualNumbers().add(args[0], args[1]));
        }
    }
}

class TextualNumbers {

    private static Pattern onlyDigits = Pattern.compile("\\A[0-9]*\\z");

    public String add(String firstAddend, String secondAddend) {
        validate(firstAddend);
        validate(secondAddend);
        PartialInputProcessor resultWithCarry = new PartialInputProcessor(0);
        int maxLen = Math.max(firstAddend.length(), secondAddend.length());
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(maxLen + 1);
        for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < maxLen; charIndex++) {
            int first = parseIntOrGet0(firstAddend, firstAddend.length() - charIndex - 1);
            int second = parseIntOrGet0(secondAddend, secondAddend.length() - charIndex - 1);
            resultWithCarry.processInputs(first, second);
            res.append(resultWithCarry.getPartialResult());
        }
        res.append(String.valueOf(resultWithCarry.getCarry()));
        String response = trimLeadingZeros(res.reverse().toString());
        return response;
    }

    private void validate(String addend) {
        if (addend == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (addend.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("[ " + addend + " ] is not a positive integer.");
        }

        if (!(onlyDigits.matcher(addend).matches())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("[ " + addend + " ] is   not a positive integer.");
        }
    }

    private int parseIntOrGet0(String intString, int charPosition) {
        if (intString.length() <= charPosition || charPosition < 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Character.digit(intString.charAt(charPosition), 10);
        }
    }

    private String trimLeadingZeros(String a) {
        while (a.startsWith("0")) {
            a = a.substring(1);
        }
        return a;
    }

}

 class PartialInputProcessor {

    private int carry;
    private String partialResult;

    public PartialInputProcessor(int initialCarry) {
        this.carry = 0;
    }

    public String getCarry() {
        return String.valueOf(carry);
    }

    public String getPartialResult() {
        return partialResult;
    }

    public void processInputs(int input1, int input2) {
        int partialSum = input1 + input2 + carry;
        carry = partialSum / 10;
        partialResult = String.valueOf(partialSum % 10);
    }

}
```

Comment: Bugfixes aside, I don't think that this refactoring is better than the original. `sumChar()` uses so many parameters that it should have stayed part of `add()`. Division and modulo operations might be slower than conditional subtraction (needs benchmarking to check). `trimTrailingZeros()` actually trims leading zeros.

Comment: In `parseIntOrGet0()`, why would `intString.length() <= charPosition` ever be true?

Comment: Caution: `Character.digit()` is quite different from `Integer.parseInt()`. The former returns -1 if the character is not a digit, which leads to laughable bugs. The latter throws `NumberFormatException`, which is the preferred behavior.

Comment: Ok, I'll add validation of input parameters; sorry for the wrong method name... Maybe I should code in Italian :D

Answer (score 4):

Your code breaks if the input strings are of different lengths.

It is important to note that you don't support negative or non-integer inputs.

I would expect the `add()` function to return the result as a String: `public static String add(String a, String b)`.  (You probably intended to do that, since you declared `myString` but never used it.)

Instead of accumulating the result in an `ArrayList<String>`, I would just use the `StringBuilder`.  (`StringBuilder` is essentially an `ArrayList` of `char`.  It even has a `.reverse()` method.)

The `carry` variable should be local to the `add()` function; there is no reason why it should be stored in the state of the class.  It's confusing, and it makes your code non-thread-safe.  (Also, `int` should be preferred over `Integer` whenever possible.)

`MyClass` is a pointless name.  `BigInteger` would be a good name, but it would be a bad idea to use the same name as a class in the standard Java library, even if they are in different packages.  Name it something similar to `BigInteger`.

Your variable names could be improved with parallelism.  It's hard to remember that `i1` and `i` correspond to `a`, and `i2` and `j` correspond to `b`.  Naming the variables `digit1`, `i1`, `addend1` and `digit2`, `i2`, `addend2` would be better.

A `while (true) { … }` loop with a `break` inside suggests that the code structure could be improved.  I think that a for-loop provides a better structure.

```
/**
 * Adds two non-negative integers represented as string of digits.
 *
 * @exception NumberFormatException if either argument contains anything other
 *            than base-10 digits.
 */
public static String add(String addend1, String addend2) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for ( int i1 = addend1.length() - 1, i2 = addend2.length() - 1, carry = 0;
          i1 >= 0 || i2 >= 0 || carry != 0;
          i1--, i2-- ) {
        int digit1 = i1 < 0 ? 0 :
                     Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(addend1.charAt(i1)));
        int digit2 = i2 < 0 ? 0 :
                     Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(addend2.charAt(i2)));

        int digit = digit1 + digit2 + carry;
        if (digit > 9) {
            carry = 1;
            digit -= 10;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }

        buf.append(digit);
    }
    return buf.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks, BTW in the next version of this code(i.e., adding numbers with lengths greater than range of long), instead of 2 numbers i want to add multiple numbers, can u give me some tips/hints how to do that

Comment: Just call add() multiple times.

Comment: If you really wanted to make an API that supported a single `add()` call, you could use a varargs argument.

Answer (score 0):

Loop structure's OK, logic's reasonably good. There is obviously a Java library alternative of `BigInteger`, but I assume you knew that. Some efficiency issues with excessive toString() and string-ification of what could be character operations.

Here are some tips:

1. Use `int` where nulls are not possible, not `Integer`.
2. `carry` is only used locally -- keep it local. Referencing it outside the method can only be erroneous, so it shouldn't be visibly exposed to make that possible..
3. Carry calculation from `i3` is OK here, but could in related algorithms be brittle -- it can't handle a digit-sum > 19 as the maximum carry it can produce is 1.
4. If addition completes with a carry of 0, it will output an unnecessary 0 digit.
5. If Strings are your inputs, you should probably build a String as the result via a StringBuilder -- not an ArrayList.
6. `myString` should be called `result` or `sb`, if you're building the result in it.
7. Build using StringBuilder in reverse order, and do it by character calculation `(char) (i3 + '0')` rather than toString() if you want to maximize efficiency.
8. Return the result from your function, and do the printing in main() instead. there. That way you have a general-purpose `add()` function and a fixed-purpose main() method for testing.

Is that complete enough?

Answer (score 0):

This is my version with basic java API's

```
package geeks.in.action.algo.numtoword;

public class AddTwoBigNumbers {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Addition:" + addIntegers("9999", "9999"));
        System.out.println("Addition:" + addIntegers("1233434323432454521", "99872343237868642"));
        System.out.println("Addition:" + addIntegers("1233434323432454521", "37868642"));
        System.out.println("Addition:" + addIntegers("37868642", "1233434323432454521"));
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static String addIntegers(String number1, String number2) throws Exception {
    validate(number1, number2);
    System.out.println("Adding: " + number1 + "+" + number2);
    char[] num1char = number1.toCharArray();
    char[] num2char = number2.toCharArray();
    if (num1char.length > num2char.length) {
        num2char = formatToSameLength(num1char, num2char);
    } else if (num1char.length < num2char.length) {
        num1char = formatToSameLength(num2char, num1char);
    }
    final char[] addition = new char[num1char.length + 1];
    char carrry = '0';
    for (int i = num1char.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final int sum = Character.getNumericValue(num1char[i]) + Character.getNumericValue(num2char[i]) + Character.getNumericValue(carrry);
        final char[] csum = String.valueOf(sum).toCharArray();
        carrry = '0';
        if (csum.length > 1 && i == 0) {
            addition[i + 1] = csum[1];
            addition[0] = csum[0];
        } else if (csum.length > 1) {
            carrry = csum[0];
            addition[i + 1] = csum[1];
        } else {
            addition[i + 1] = csum[0];
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(addition);
}

private static void validate(String number1, String number2) throws Exception {
    if (number1.trim().isEmpty() || number2.trim().isEmpty() || !isNumber(number1) || !isNumber(number2)) {
        throw new Exception("Number is not present or not a valid number");
    }
}

private static boolean isNumber(String number) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(number);
        return true;
    } catch (final NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    return false;
}

private static char[] formatToSameLength(char[] num1char, char[] num2char) {
    final int diff = num1char.length - num2char.length;
    final char[] num = new char[num1char.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
        num[i] = '0';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num2char.length; i++) {
        num[diff + i] = num2char[i];
    }
    return num;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Answering with your own version is correct, but what we like here is the why. Why your solution is better?

Comment: This code looks neat, and accurate.... but ... Code Review answers should do more than just 'dump' an alternative solution to a problem. Answers should at least explain why the alternative is better, and what problems the alternative solves that the original code does not. We have [a meta post that covers this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers)